# Frobenius group and conjugacy relation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, frobenius-groups

I try to solve the following problem (problem 6.A.4 from M.Isaacs Ginite Group Theory)

> Let $G$ be a Frobenius group with Frobenius kernel $N$. Show that each
>   coset  of $N$ in $G$ other than $N$ itself is contained in a single
>   conjugacy class of $G$.

My attempt was to show that $Ng \subseteq g^G$ for every $g\notin N$, but I cannot prove this. Also I tried to prove by the contrary but also stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$C_N(g)=1$  so $g$ has $|N|$ conjugates under $N$, which. must be the elements of $Ng$.